# Distribution of variance of $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ$?

Tags: variance, asymptotics

I had a question that I couldn't quite wrap my mind around.

Essentially, it's this. Suppose $x_i$ is a random $k$-vector, and $X$ is an $n\times k$ vector that is $n$ i.i.d. copies of this $x_i$ "stacked" on each other. Suppose $Z$ is a random $n$ vector. Suppose we're interested in the variance of the vector $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ$ as a random variable. Can we say anything about this random variable after appropriate standardization (for instance, a central limit theorem type result)? Let's say that the random $k$-vector $X^TZ$ is mean zero and asymptotically normally distributed such that $n^{1/2}X^TZ \to_d N(0, V)$.

From what I can gather, if we assume certain moments exist (let's also say the expectation of the cross product $E(x_ix_i^T) = H$ exists), we can get *something*, but for each element of the vector $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ$, I feel like the asymptotic variance EXISTS, I'm just not sure if I can say anything about an appropriately standardized asymptotic distribution (i.e., standardizing by $\sqrt(n)$ and substracting some "true" quantity.

This is not for homework or anything, just personal interest.

Comment: What is the dimension of $X(X^TX)^{-1}$?

Comment: Good point, it's not actually a vector (should've caught that!). Since $X$ is $n \times p$, $(X^TX)^{-1}$ would be $p \times p$, and hence $X(X^TX)^{-1}$ would be an $n \times p$ matrix. I'll edit my post to be a question that makes sense!

Comment: For non-Bayesian, variance is a constant, known or unknown, and is not random thing. So variance has no distribution.